# CSS image margin-bottom

Tags: html, css

I have one container "body_step". In this container are two areas. The first one is the picture and the second one the text. I placed the image inside a container "image_step". Now I want to add a margin-bottom at the image. But if i write `margin-bottom: 5px;` it will do `margin-bottom: 25px;`. I dont want to change the `line-height`. 
Here is the Code:

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Oswald",sans-serif;
}

body{
    background-color: rgb(38, 38, 38)
}

nav{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
}


.navbar_ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 800px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar_li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px; 
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

a{
    color: #666;
    display: block;
    transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}

a:hover{
    color: #CCC;
}

section{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    width: 1012px;
}

.clearBoth {
  clear:both;
}

article{
    width: 750px;
    border: 3px solid rgb(30, 30, 30);
    background-color: rgb(75, 75, 75);
    float: left;
}

aside{
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
}

.step{
    width: 100%;
}

.header_step{
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(30, 30, 30);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}

.body_step{
    width 730px;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: justify;
}

.image_step{
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>XXX</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="title.png" type="image/png" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul class="navbar_ul">
                <li class="navbar_li"><a href="http://www.google.de">Seite erstellen</a></li>
                <li class="navbar_li"><a href="http://www.google.de">Seite löschen</a></li>
                <li class="navbar_li"><a href="http://www.google.de">Seite bearbeiten</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <section>
            <article>
                <div class="step">
                    <div class="header_step">Hier steht die Überschrift</div>
                    <div class="body_step"><img class="image_step" src="bg.png" height="500px" width="500px">Hier steht Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim v</div>
                </div>
                <div class="step">
                    <div class="header_step">Hier steht die Überschrift</div>
                    <div class="body_step"><img class="image_step" src="bg.png" height="50px" width="100px">Hier Hier steht Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim vHier steht Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim vHier steht Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim vsteht Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim v</div>
                </div>
                <div class="step">
                    <div class="header_step">Hier steht die Überschrift</div>
                    <div class="body_step"><img class="image_step" src="bg.png" height="300px" width="500px">Hier stHier steht Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim vHier steht Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim vHier steht Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veht Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim v</div>
                </div>
            </article>
            
            <aside>
            <a class="asd">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsu. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequatm dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</a>
            </aside>
            
            <div class="clearBoth"></div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

**My Question:** how can I give the image a `margin-bottom: 5px`?

Comment: Your image IS having `margin-bottom: 5px;`

Comment: In your code, the images have `margin-bottom:5px` but I don't see where it is that ***it gets*** `margin-bottom:25px`. Maybe you mean that the under the small image there is a big space?

Comment: Yes, i mean the big space

Comment: This actually happens because the image has enough height to put the third line on the left. To fix this you can either reduce the `margin-bottom` to a value less than `5px` of set the image to a slightly smaller height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting your image to:

```
display:block;
```

or

```
display:inline-block;
```

depending on the rest of your layout

Comment: can you provide an URL?

Comment: I thin k I get it now, my bad it's just that the image height to line-height ratio is not a perfect fit, so there is no way for the text line under the to get "closer" to the image as it just breakes a new line to the text above it

Comment: wait which image do you mean has a "magin of 25px"

Comment: every image  got a margin-bottom of 25px

Comment: No it does not see the explanation above that is just the only way that the text can warp aroud set height 43px for the small image for example and see for yourself

Comment: I have a idea. Maybe i can set the imaeg into a container?

Comment: what? no you do not need a container, nothing is wrong on your website that is normal behaviour, how else would you even expect that text to get closet to the image? by overlapping the row above it?

Comment: hmm, I dont know. But in my opinion it looks terriblle, do you know the standart line height?

Comment: line-height is what you set it but most browsers set it to about 1.2em, just set your image heights to a multiple of your line height

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, that a user can upload a image and i dont know the size^^ But i wrote a little programm in PHP and now it works. Thanks for you help!